# How to access the topmost UINavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have displayed two NavigationControllers in my iOS app. I need to access the topmost NavigationController programmatically. I tried

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController
```

but it returns the bottom NavigationController. How could I access the UINavigationController which is on the top using Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PresentingViewController` property of the bottom navigation controller to reach to it's displaying controller, and then use the `navigationController` of the said controller.

something like this:

```
[[bottomNavController presentingViewController] navigationController]
```

but I strongly suggest that instead of this approach you walk up trough all your presenting controllers and find the last navigation controller that exists in the chain.

Cheers